# Android fragment.. i want my text on another fragment after select view menu on context menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-contextmenu

i want to get item at position text on another fragment

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 

    // Get extra info about list item that was long-pressed
    AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

    // Perform action according to selected item from context menu
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case CONTEXTMENU_OPTION1:
        // Show message
        Fragment fragment = new detail();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("Menuu",getActivity().getApplicationContext().toString());
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,fragment).addToBackStack("mm").commit();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "View", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
```

Comment: what ? explain it clearly .

Comment: What do you want to do? Provide more details

Answer (score 0):

The `getItemId()` provides you with an integer (*position of the item in the menu..first being 0, etc.*).

I don't understand your question, but if you are trying to open another fragment, with clicking on an item in your Menu. Then your switch should look like:

```
switch(item.getItemId()){
//This will be initialized if the user selects first item in Men
case 0:
/** replace your fragment uppon clicking the first item in menu*/
break;
```

etc.

If this is not what you seek for, then I didn't understand your question. Also we don't know what `CONTEXTMENU_OPTION1`
is in your case.